# Retrieving a User's Location from a GPS-enabled Phone in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, geolocation

I need to build a Visualforce page where a sales agent can see all his tasks and his current location on a google map. Now I know how to show the tasks as markers on a google map, but how can I retrieve the current user location?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Yeah nothing special about vf. This is just a js question and should be asked on [so].